# RequireJS/Backbone: Getting view returned from require

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

Here is my view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tablesView'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView) {
    require(['collections/tablesCollection'], function(tablesCollection) {
        var t = new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'main-contact'});
        var tables = new tablesView({ collection: t, template: 'main-contact-template'});
        tables.url = 'main-contact';
        return tables;  // <!-- returns view, tables can be console.log'ed
    });

    console.log(tables); // <!-- tables is not defined
});
```

How do I get the `tables` within the `require` statement so that is accessible where the `console.log` is?  This seems to be where I need to return the view from, so I can use it in my route:

```
app_router.on('route:index', function(){
        require(['views/tables/mainContactView'], function(mainContactView) {
            console.log(mainContactView);  // <!-- undefined, unless some value is returned from where the console.log() is above
            $('#web-leads').html(mainContactView.render().el);
        });
    });
```

If I put `return 'test'` where the `console.log(tables)` is, I can `console.log()` it in my route.  So I assume that's where I need to return the view from.  How do I pass that data out?  Right now, even with a return statement, my view is undefined.  I need to get the view out of the `require`.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already loaded `collection/tablesCollection` in define, so you don't have to do another `require` to get it loaded.

You can simply the definition of the View as this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',   // You've already required tablesCollection here.
    'views/tablesView'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView) {
    var t = new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'main-contact'});
    var tables = new tablesView({ collection: t, template: 'main-contact-template'});
    tables.url = 'main-contact';
    return tables;
});
```